# How to pass a reference to distribution home directory using Gradle application plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, home-directory

I'm using a Gradle application plugin and I want to create distribution which contains **conf** directory inside app home folder. This dir should contain several configuration files. e.g. *java.util.logging* properties, etc. To point JUL my configuration file I should pass jvm property `-Djava.util.logging.config=...` and here I need a reference to app installation directory. It seems that scripts set this path into **APP_HOME** variable. But there is a problem: I cannot pass into *defaultJvmOpts* property something like `$APP_HOME` since there are two kinds of scripts (win and nix) and moreover dollar sign is unconditionally escaped.

So, is there any way to pass a reference to app home directory as a virtual machine argument?

Answer (score 1):

Luke Daley posted an answer to the question on the Gradle forum:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_pass_a_reference_to_distribution_home_directory_using_application_plugin:

> You'll have to augment the start scripts.
>
> There's an example of this here: https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/blob/master/ratpack-gradle/src/main/groovy/ratpack/gradle/RatpackPlugin.groovy#L93

Thanks to him for help.

So, I added the following code to the end of my `build.gradle`:

```
CreateStartScripts startScripts = project.startScripts
startScripts.with {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replaceFirst('(?<=DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=)((\'|\")(.*)(\'|"))(?=\n)',
                '\'$3 "-Dtcproxy.config.url=file:\\$APP_HOME/conf/proxy.properties"\'')
        windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replaceFirst('(?<=DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=)(.*)(?=\r\n)',
                '$1 "-Dtcproxy.config.url=file:%~dp0../conf/proxy.properties"')
    }
}
```

And it works! Hope later such functionality will be added to the plugin.